# Expected value of two different random variables

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, independence

I am a bit confused. We have two different random variables $X,Y$ and another two random variables $G,F$, such that $G$ has the same distribution as $X$ and $F$ has the same distribution as $Y$.
Does
\begin{align*}
E(XY)=E(GF)
\end{align*}
hold?
Or do we need some independence assumptions?
Sorry for this silly qustion:)

Comment: The expectation is completely determined by the distribution, so it is true that $E(XY)=E(GF)$. What you would need independence for is, for example, to ensure that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.

Comment: No it is not true in general, since you didn't specify any constraints on the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ and $(G, F)$. If you had said that $(X,Y)$ and $(G,F)$ had the same distribution, then yes $\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[GF]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need information regarding the joint distribution.

Counterexample:

Suppose all $4$ variables are $\pm 1$ with equal probability.

Scenario $1$:  They are pairwise independent.  Then both $XY$ and $GF$ are also $\pm 1$ with equal probability so both expectations are $0$ (in particular, they are equal).

Scenario $2$:  $X,Y$ are pairwise independent but $G=F$.  Then $E(XY)=0$ as before but $GF$ is the constant $1$, hence has expectation $1$.